# Elastisearch query filter

Tags: elasticsearch, query-builder

I am trying to make a query with a filter on my index but when I try to filter on any attribute in the mapping the query returns no result.

The query is the following, if I run just with the geo_distance part I get results. I would like to filter the results using one of the properties in the mapping (in this case rating, but it can be city, state ecc).
Query is generated in Java via QueryBuilder from elasticsearch library (v 52.0). But for now I am trying to understand how to build a working query and executing via CURL.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "geo_distance": {
            "geometry.coordinates": [
              12.3232,
              12.2323
            ],
            "distance": 200000,
            "distance_type": "plane",
            "validation_method": "STRICT",
            "ignore_unmapped": false,
            "boost": 1
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "terms": {
                  "rating": [
                    "0"
                  ],
                  "boost": 1
                }
              }
            ],
            "adjust_pure_negative": true,
            "boost": 1
          }
        }
      ],
      "adjust_pure_negative": true,
      "boost": 1
    }
  }
}
```

If I run a query filtering on zipcode or id it works.
For example a query like this:

```
{"query":{"bool":{"filter":{"term":{"zipCode":"111111"}}}}}
```

A snippet of my mapping is this

```
{
  "my_index": {
    "mappings": {
      "poielement": {
        "dynamic_templates": [
          {
            "suggestions": {
              "match": "suggest_*",
              "mapping": {
                "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
                "copy_to": "auto_suggest",
                "search_analyzer": "my_analyzer",
                "store": true,
                "type": "text"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "integers": {
              "match_mapping_type": "long",
              "mapping": {
                "type": "text"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "geopoint": {
              "match": "coordinates",
              "mapping": {
                "type": "geo_point"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "property": {
              "match": "*",
              "mapping": {
                "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
                "search_analyzer": "my_analyzer"
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "date_detection": false,
        "numeric_detection": false,
        "properties": {
          "city": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
          },
          "country": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
          },
          "geometry": {
            "properties": {
              "coordinates": {
                "type": "geo_point"
              },
              "type": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
              }
            }
          },
          "id": {
            "type": "text"
          },
          "name": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "rating": {
            "type": "text"
          },
          "total_rate": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
          },
          "type": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
          },
          "zipCode": {
            "type": "text"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I retrieve data via http://elasticsearchpat/my_index/_search data looks like this

```
{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 4,
    "successful": 4,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 7517,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "my_index",
        "_type": "poielement",
        "_id": "58768",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "zipCode": 111111,
          "country": "USA",
          "city": "Portland",
          "rating": 0,
          "type": "",
          "id": 123,
          "geometry": {
            "coordinates": [
              12.205061,
              12.490463
            ],
            "type": "Point"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I will be very grateful for any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this query instead

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "rating": 0
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "geo_distance": {
            "geometry.coordinates": [
              12.3232,
              12.2323
            ],
            "distance": 200000,
            "distance_type": "plane",
            "validation_method": "STRICT",
            "ignore_unmapped": false,
            "boost": 1
          }
        }
      ],
      "adjust_pure_negative": true,
      "boost": 1
    }
  }
}
```